# How to use switch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have been trying to make a password generator and I have this code and it is returning "undefined" not a character. The code is supposed to return 16 characters with numbers, lower and upper characters. I want to have this so that I don't have to worry about making my own passwords anymore.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PassGen</title>
  <script>
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    function num2lett(num) {
      switch (num) {
        case (num > 36):
          return String.fromCharCode(577 + num - 35);
          break;
        case (num > 10 && num < 37):
          return String.fromCharCode(97 + num - 11);
          break;
        case (num == 10):
          return "0";
          break;
        case (num < 10):
          return "" + num;
          break;
      }

    }

    function uuidMake() {
      var uuid = "";
      for (u = 0; u < 16; u++) {
        randNum = getRandomInt(0, 62);
        uuid += num2lett(randNum);
      }
      document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = uuid;
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: "uuid_font";
      src: url("Courier Prime Code.ttf") format("TrueType");
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #262626;
    }
    
    #password {
      font-family: "uuid_font";
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #dddddd;
      margin-top: 250px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <p id="password" onclick="uuidMake();">Click Me</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use case statements like if else so just use if else condition that will work like as following example.

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function num2lett(num) {
  if (num > 36)
    return String.fromCharCode(577 + num - 35);
  else if (num > 10 && num < 37)
    return String.fromCharCode(97 + num - 11);
  else if (num == 10)
    return "0";
  else if (num < 10)
    return "" + num;
}

function uuidMake() {
  var uuid = "";
  for (u = 0; u < 16; u++) {
    randNum = getRandomInt(0, 62);
    uuid += num2lett(randNum);
  }
  document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = uuid;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "uuid_font";
  src: url("Courier Prime Code.ttf") format("TrueType");
}

body {
  background-color: #262626;
}

#password {
  font-family: "uuid_font";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #dddddd;
  margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<p id="password" onclick="uuidMake();">Click Me</p>
```

What is your algorithm I don't know so I am just converted your algorithm to if else

Comment: Most of this is working, I'm a bit worried about the caps letters though, any idea on how to fix that? I though it was 577 (unicode)

Comment: Replace this line first if condition by this line **if (num > 36) return String.fromCharCode(65 + num - 35);**

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a good use case for `switch`. Use `if` and `else` statements.

The `case`s in a `switch` statement are specific possible values of the expression that you're `switch`ing on. For instance, one might write something like:

```
switch (n) {
    case 1:
        // things to do when n is 1
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
        // things to do when n is 3 or 4
        break;
    default:
        // things to do when n is neither 1, 3, nor 4
}
```

A `case` statement cannot be a range of values. Using an expression as a `case` is not recommended, either -- it isn't *invalid*, but it will probably not do what you expect either.

Answer (score 1):

In the `switch` block, you have written conditional statements in the `case`.

You can't use conditional statements in the `switch` block. Hence in your case none of the `case` are executing. As you don't have a `default` block, your function doesn't returns anything, which in case of javascript is `undefined`. Hence you are getting `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can alter switch statement to make it work. Pass 'true' in switch and remove parentheses from case condition

```
switch (true) {
   case num > 36:
```